# Function kbhit to move object in C

Tags: c, move, kbhit

This program is detecting right keyboard keys, but when I am trying to move object by pressing arrow on my keyboard, but when i do this it goes in the same line, no matter which arrow i am pressing.
I am asking for help to move this object in different possitions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
COORD coord={0, 0};

struct Ship{
    int x,y;
}Ship;
struct Ship S;
void gotoxy (int x, int y){
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y; // X and Y coordinates
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
void print()
{
    system("CLS");
    coord.X = 0;
    coord.Y = 0;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
        printf (">");
} 

int main(){
    time_t last_change = clock();
    int game=1;
    int speed=300;
    print();
    int x=0, y=0;

    while (game==1){
            if (kbhit()){
                int c = getch();
                //printf("%d",c);
                if (c==224){
                    c = getch();
                    //printf("%d",c);
                    switch (c){
                        case 72: {y--;printf(">");}
                        break;
                        case 80: {y++;printf(">");}
                        break;
                        case 77: {x++;printf(">");}
                        break;
                        case 75: {x--;printf(">");}
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
        last_change= clock();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling the `gotoxy` function, all you do is `printf(">");`

So add that in each of the `case` blocks, like this one

```
case 72: y--;
         gotoxy(x, y);
         printf(">");
         break;
```

Now you can drive the `>` character around the screen, leaving its trail.

Note that you should check that `x` and `y` stay within limits.

```
case 72: if (y > 0) {
             y--;
             gotoxy(x, y);
             printf(">");
         }
         break;
```

Comment: Going in one line when you press what key? You have to change all the cases, not just one.

Comment: it still goes in one lane even if i changed as you said :(

Comment: switch (c){
                        case 72: y++;
              gotoxy(x, y);
              printf(">");
              break;
                        case 80: y--;
              gotoxy(x, y);
              printf(">");
              break;
                        case 77: x++;
              gotoxy(x, y);
              printf(">");
              break;
                        case 75: x--;
              gotoxy(x, y);
              printf(">");

Comment: Which key are you pressing? Left arrow? Add the limits.

Comment: i am pressing all arrows and it goes in same line :P

Comment: Your code in comments does not check any limits. My test program behaves nicely.

Comment: What do you mean by adding limits?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. If the position is at the left, you don't want to try moving it to the left.